# Modify Duplicate values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of cells which have a value for each. These values are linked to a students name. I am trying to identify the lowest 5 students based on this value. I have this formula to find the lowest values -

=SMALL(FilteredData[DARTOPIMaths],COUNTIF(FilteredData[DARTOPIMaths],"<="&K2)+1)

and this formula to then lookup the name that relates to this value -

=INDEX(SurnameForenameFiltered,MATCH(K3,FilteredData[DARTOPIMaths],0))

This works fine but my issue is when I have two students with the same value. It then reports back the first name twice. I have tried to make the values unique without changing the original value but I cannot get this to work.

I really need to be able to find the bottom 5 and then list the students names. If two students have the same value it selects both students names.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We can de-conflict the duplicates.  Say we have data like:

[image]

A number of the scores are duplicated, so in **C1** we enter:

```
 =B1
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=(COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)-1)*0.0001+B2
```

and copy down:

[image]

The values in the helper column are all unique.  In **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(SMALL(C:C,ROW()),C:C,0))
```

and copy down.  In **F1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(SMALL(C:C,ROW()),C:C,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

This modification of duplicate values approach avoids the need for array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it (I copied the table that @GaryStudent used).

- Determine which "lowest" you want and put that value in D1 (`5` in this example)
- Create an array of results of `TRUE/FALSE` depending on whether a score is less than or equal to the `d1`th lowest score
- multiply that array by an array of the row numbers, to obtain the appropriate row
- the addition of `1/1/(array)` changes this to an array of `DIV/0` errors and the row number.
- Use the SMALL argument of the aggregate function to return only those values which are NOT errors.
- Use that result to Index into the table and return both the Name and the score.
- I used structured references as you did.

Note that this could return more than five students, in view of the possibility of ties

```
F1: =IFERROR(INDEX(StudentScores[#All],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/1/(StudentScores[Score] <= SMALL(StudentScores[Score],$D$1))*ROW(StudentScores),ROWS($1:1)),1),"")

G1: =IFERROR(INDEX(StudentScores[#All],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/1/(StudentScores[Score] <= SMALL(StudentScores[Score],$D$1))*ROW(StudentScores),ROWS($1:1)),2),"")
```

[image]

Of course, you could also use the `Advanced Filter`, with a formula as a criteria, and write the results to a "NEW" location.  But it might not be as dynamic as what you require.